# Airflow Dag doesnot fail on python script failure

Tags: python, python-2.7, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

I am using some python scripts to download the files from the ftp server and I have created the DAG for this. Some times the python script while downloading the file from FTP server fails on "Peer connection reset error" but airflow DAG doesnot fail and it marks task as success instead of failing it.

```
Below are airflow logs for more information.


[2019-01-03 19:04:40,085] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask: [2019-01-03 19:04:40,085] {ssh_execute_operator.py:146} INFO - [2019-01-03 19:09:14,276 - Download files from SFTP - ERROR] Total 1 file(s) ([u'R0000797-Manifest.xml']) are downloaded successfully. One error is found in downloading file xxxxxx.txt due to Server connection dropped:
[2019-01-03 19:04:40,091] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask: [2019-01-03 19:04:40,090] {ssh_execute_operator.py:146} INFO - [2019-01-03 19:09:14,282 - Download files from SFTP - ERROR] The whole process failed due to Server connection dropped: .
[2019-01-03 19:04:40,091] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask: [2019-01-03 19:04:40,091] {ssh_execute_operator.py:146} INFO - Total 1 file(s) ([u'R0000797-Manifest.xml']) are downloaded successfully.
[2019-01-03 19:04:40,092] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask: [2019-01-03 19:04:40,091] {ssh_execute_operator.py:146} INFO - Traceback (most recent call last):
[2019-01-03 19:04:40,092] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask: [2019-01-03 19:04:40,091] {ssh_execute_operator.py:146} INFO - main(args)
[2019-01-03 19:04:40,092] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask: [2019-01-03 19:04:40,091] {ssh_execute_operator.py:146} INFO - File "/TEST/GET_files.py", line 381, in main
[2019-01-03 19:04:40,093] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask: [2019-01-03 19:04:40,092] {ssh_execute_operator.py:146} INFO - sftp.get(source_file)


As you can see from above logs that python script gave a proper error message to airflow handler but airflow handler shows that message as INFO and it doesn't fail. So please can you suggest me or help me in this scenario? I want to fail the DAG task when any python error occurs. 

************************************
here is the dag code

get_files = SSHExecuteOperator(
    task_id='get_files',
    bash_command=command to run the py script,
    ssh_hook=sshHook,
    dag=dag)

************************************

Expected results: The airflow DAG should fail when python script fails.
Thanks for your help in advance.
```

Comment: Can you post the python code? It looks like you may be catching the failure to log it . You may need to raise an exception so that it doesn't exits with a value of 1 rather than 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `set -e;` to your `bash_command`. For example:

```
get_files = SSHExecuteOperator(
    task_id='get_files',
    bash_command='set -e; python example_script.py',
    ssh_hook=sshHook,
    dag=dag)
```

Comment: I am facing the same problem as OP, your solution seemed to have worked for him but for me, it's not working. You can see my dag [here](https://freetexthost.net/CkbUgAf). `python3` does not have the packages/modules script requires & thus it gives error when ran on terminal but it gives `success` status on airflow. Can you please check what I am doing wrong?

Comment: @saadi You need to have `set -e` in your `bash_command`, you have `set e` :)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a PythonOperator?

Example here : https://github.com/trbs/airflow-examples/blob/master/dags/example_python_operator.py

Doc here: https://airflow.apache.org/_modules/airflow/operators/python_operator.html